# Is it possbile to show how many EXPECT_* calls are made in the output of gtest

Tags: unit-testing, googletest

I found the google test framework shows **only failure reports**.  Is it possible to show the **pass checks** in the report (stdout and xml)?

For example, show the `EXPECT_*` count in the report.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't possible without hacking the gtest source code to do what you want.

You can [set up event listeners](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Extending_Google_Test_by_Handling_Test_Events) to customise the behaviour of gtest, and I think the closest thing to what you want would be the `TestPartResult`, but this is only fired on a failed assertion or a `SUCCEED()`, so the successful assertions and expectations don't trigger any event.

I believe [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) may provide something more like this though.